# Add border to the first slide in Xaringan with CSS

Tags: css, r-markdown, xaringan

I would like to include a red border to the first xaringan slide:

This is my Rmd code:

```
    ---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, PBC"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ['presentation_1.css']
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

# First Slide



---
# Second Slide

---
# Third Slide

---
# Fourth Slide

---
```

In css file I did:

```
.remark-slides-area div:first-child {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Why it didnt work?

Comment: inspect it on console if the css applied and just been overwrite. if thats the case you could add !important

Comment: or you could they .remark-slides-area div:nth-child(1)

Comment: @Mcfaith `.remark-slides-area div:nth-child(1)` didnt work. I want to include a red border only on the first slide. When I set: `.remark-slides-area div:nth-child(1) {border: 5px solid red}` this includes a border on all slides.

Comment: Could you please directly post an example of the generated HTML?

Comment: @johannchopin I dont know how to do this. The HTML file or xaringan is huge. I will see how can I posti it here. But this example is not running for you? I created a .rmd file and its reproducible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the title slide the first slide then:

```css
.title-slide {
    border: 5px red solid;
}
```

Or, if the first slide is not the title:

```css
.remark-slide-container:first-child .remark-slide-content {
    border: 5px red solid;
}
```

You can also try this which is close to your attempt:

```css
.remark-slides-area > div:first-child {
    border: 5px solid red
}
```